# What is the proper way to bind cell views to model objects in NSTableView / UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have constructed a view-based NSTableView, programmatically (code-only, without XIB) following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599747/programmatically-creating-an-nstableview-trouble-getting-the-nsheaderview-to-sh), which is backed by an NSArrayController, created simply by: `var controller = NSArrayController()` and bound to the table by:

```
tableView.bind(NSContentBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath: "arrangedObjects", options: nil)
tableView.bind(NSSelectionIndexesBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath:"selectionIndexes", options: nil)
tableView.bind(NSSortDescriptorsBinding, toObject: controller, withKeyPath: "sortDescriptors", options: nil)
```

I only use the `controller`'s methods to add/remove objects, and get them by: `(controller.arrangedObjects as! NSArray)[index]` . The items in the array are of a Class with `String?` or `dynamic Double` fields and they extend from `NSObject`.

Adding and removing rows inside the model automatically adds/removes the corresponding rows in the table, but I cannot bind the cell views to the items -and observe changes in their fields-. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34586387/3648895) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33632495/3648895) with no luck. Final version of my cell view is like:

```
class PLTextCellView: NSTextField {
    init(columnName:String) {
        //.... erased...
        self.columnName = columnName
    }
    var columnName = ""

    var displayText:AnyObject {
        get {
            return stringValue
        }
        set(val) {
            stringValue = String(val)
        }
    }

    weak
    var item:PLItem? = nil

    override
    var objectValue: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            item = objectValue as? PLItem
            if (item != nil) {
                Swift.print("item to bind is:\(item) ")
                unbind("displayText")
//                bind("displayText", toObject: self.item!, withKeyPath: columnName, options: [NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption:"--"])
                bind("displayText", toObject: self, withKeyPath: "objectValue."+columnName, options: [NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption:"--"])
            } else {
                Swift.print("unbinding... ")
                unbind("displayText")
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        unbind("displayText")
    }

    override
    func prepareForReuse() {
        unbind("displayText")
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }
    ///... erased ....
}
```

If I don't use any binding, I only get **`item`** object ids displayed on the table on each and every column, even if I explicitly set `displayText` (so something must be internally setting the text !!)

Question **1:** If I use the commented/first `bind` line, each `item` object prints a different object id to the console -even if some represent the same object- and none of them exist in the `controller`! Why **?**

Question **2:** If I use the uncommented/second `bind` line, I get this error: `An instance of ...item... was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25057388/3648895) says I should not do binding/observing in the cell view, but the most convenient place seems the cell view (for MVC). I don't know a way to remove all -view-bindings in the model items in their `deinit`s. (Interestingly, I even don't delete any items from the `controller`).

As I understand from the related questions and answers, this question also holds for `UITableView`'s. So, what is the proper way to do the binding **?**

Comment: Is there any reason you're using an ``NSTextField`` subclass as your *cell*? Why don't you want to use the ``NSTableCellView`` class?

Comment: In its header file it had just 2 fields: a text and an image. If I can attach any subview in it and can make this binding problem solved with it, why not?

Comment: Before you start doing unconventional things in your code, make sure that you can get things working in a more conventional set-upfirst. It's pretty rare to use a non-``NSTableCellView`` subclass as your cell view (I've never done it) so I'd advise you to avoid this if you can. This  link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992756/is-it-possible-to-create-a-view-based-nstableview-purely-in-code/34131404#34131404 - takes you to a question that describes how to set up a table-view in code (note also the link to a demo project in one of the comments)

Comment: @PaulPatterson Extending from `NSTableCellView` had no effect. Modified your demo a bit to reflect my scenario; it is [here](http://jmp.sh/b/XaTptb0b2qboJ46g7Nll). All the information is included in the comment block at the beginning of the source file(AppDelegate). I believe you'll understand what I'm trying to achieve, in just a few minutes by reading it and running the project.

Comment: **Mistake 1**: if you're using an array controller to provide the table-view with its data you don't need a data-source (the array controller is the data-source). **Mistake 2**: the fields you're binding to must be marked dynamic otherwise any changes you make to them won't be noticed by whatever is observing them. **Mistake 3**: the binding you set up uses an incomplete key-path - it should point to the property (e.g. ``val1``),  not the instance (``Item``). In short you need to read the ``KVO`` and ``KVC`` guides - these are the technologies that underpin bindings. (http://jmp.sh/LEWLUmS)

Comment: @PaulPatterson, correcting Mistakes 2 & 3 solved this problem; I will gratefully accept as an answer if you paste them. For Mistake 1: I am implementing Drag&Drop, I made some Google'ing but could not find any alternative solution other than using a dataSource and implementing (only) Drag&Drop related methods, unless you know of another solution? I also have (another) performance related question below:

Comment: @PaulPatterson, I made a test for cell reuse/creation (uploaded [here](http://jmp.sh/b/1FVUAWHb0XzEKa0tXBjy), if you want to test it yourself): Double clicking on the table adds a new row to the table. After row number _(number of visible rows)*2_ {alias: _2v#r_ }, each row is created, meaning the table only/always keeps _2v#r*(number of columns)_ cell views, the rest is always re-created (cell creation code is run for the rest ( _(all rows in the table)-2v#r)_ rows). Is this the normal behavior, and logical performance-wise ?